# Error while installing wordpress on CentOS 7

Tags: wordpress, centos7

I´ve got a problem with installing wordpress on centos 7. 
I used this guide to install it cause I´m quite new to linux:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-7

I did everything step by step but it didn´t work. So I decided to reinstall my root server cause I wanted to have a new clean machine on which I could try it again. Then I used this guide to install it:

http://www.linuxveda.com/2015/09/15/install-wordpress-centos-7/

Same error as before..

The last entries in my error_log are:

[Wed Apr 13 12:16:06.794902 2016] [:error] [pid 23495] [client 66.249.93.167:41393] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:06.794974 2016] [:error] [pid 23495] [client 66.249.93.167:41393] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/Soluna/homepages/stormcloud/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:07.352614 2016] [:error] [pid 23496] [client 79.196.171.71:51928] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:07.352706 2016] [:error] [pid 23496] [client 79.196.171.71:51928] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/Soluna/homepages/stormcloud/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:07.671419 2016] [:error] [pid 23497] [client 5.79.100.165:49709] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:07.671488 2016] [:error] [pid 23497] [client 5.79.100.165:49709] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/Soluna/homepages/stormcloud/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:18.058248 2016] [:error] [pid 23494] [client 79.196.171.71:51933] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:18.058303 2016] [:error] [pid 23494] [client 79.196.171.71:51933] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/Soluna/homepages/stormcloud/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:21.985259 2016] [:error] [pid 23495] [client 79.196.171.71:51934] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 12:16:21.985311 2016] [:error] [pid 23495] [client 79.196.171.71:51934] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/Soluna/homepages/stormcloud/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Can anyone help me? Since now I´ve got nothing installed on the server except teamspeak 3. On my old root server (Hetzner Online) everything worked well but now it doesn´t...Any ideas of how to fix it? I already changed the permissions of all wordpress files but still the same error..

Answer (score 0):

They key is

> Permission denied

Check permissions of the folder and files where you are storaging your wordpress files, apache should be able to read them.

Comment: I just solved the problem...The error was caused by SELinux which was installed on the machine. No idea why...I just turned it off and it worked!